# Visual Studio 2012: How do I put the toolbox back in its default position?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, toolbox

Somehow, I moved the toolbox in my Visual Studio 2012 installation away from its default position along the left edge of my display.  I'm used to it being there, and I want to put it back, but I don't see a way to do it.  How can I get it there?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can just drag and drop tool windows in Visual Studio and they will "stick" to their new position

Comment: No, it's not working for me.  I can drag and drop it, so that it will end up in a docked window on the left, but that's not what I want.  I want the word "Toolbox" to appear on the extreme left edge, drawn from top to bottom.  Currently, I have "Data Sources" there, and I want "Toolbox" to appear in the same place.  That is its default position, but I can't get it back there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the comments to your question it sounds like want the toolbox tool window to be hidden.  Only the name "Toolbox" should appear and it should be aligned vertically (top to bottom) instead of horizontally.  To get that do the following

1. Drag the toolbox tool window over to the left side of the screen and drop it
2. There will be 3 icons on the top right of the tool window.  Click the middle one which looks like a pin

This will get it back in the default position

Answer (score 6):

Click **WINDOW** And select **Reset Window Layout**

Answer (score 1):

Using this: Alt + Ctrl + x. Then Toolbox tag will pop out.